# Is it possible to normalize the table so that it can contain one Value in one row?

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing three column BusNo, BusRoute & BusStop where BusStop column contain multiple comma separated values. I want to normalize it so that the table contain one stop in one Row.  Ex.

```
BusNo  BusRoute                BusStop  
1      Rajendra Nagar to Noida Apsara,Shahadara,Shakarpur,Mother Dairy
```

I want to make the stops in multiple row would it be good approach I have more that 1000 BusNo here.

Comment: I suspect that busno is a poor PK. I don't no how it works in Delhi, but in London, route numbers do (very) occasionally change.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to have two new tables: `BusStops` and `BusRouteBusStops`.

`BusStops` will have one line for each bus stop, containing at least two columns: `StopNumber` and `StopName`.
`BusRouteBusStops` will be the table that links the `BusRoute` table with the `BusStops` table. Each line in this table will have a primary key from `BusRoutes` and from `BusStops`.

The idea is to keep the bus stops in a table, regardless of if and where they are used. That way you can use a single stop in however many routes you want. Also, if you decide to remove a stop from all the routes, it is still kept and is available for use for new routes.
If you want to represent the *order* of the bus stops in the route, it can be added as a column to the BusRouteBusStops table.

Tables example:

```
Table BusRoutes - primary-Key(BusNo)
===============
BusNo | BusRoute
1     | Rajendra Nagar to Noida

Table BusStops - primary-Key(StopNumber)
===============
StopNumber | StopName
1          | Apsara
2          | Shahadara
3          | Shakarpur
4          | Other Stop
5          | Mother Dairy

Table BusRouteBusStops - primary-Key(BusNo+StopNumber)
===============
BusNo | StopNumber | stpoOrder
1     | 1          | 1
1     | 2          | 2
1     | 3          | 3
1     | 5          | 4
```

A query to get all the bus numbers that go through a given stop (say: Apsara), using MySql syntax, will be:

```
SELECT BR.* 
FROM BusRoutes BR, BusStops BS, BusRouteBusStops BRBS
WHERE BR.BusNo=BRBS.BusNo
AND BS.StopNumber=BRBS.StopNumber
AND BS.StopName="Apsara"
```

Comment: what about the condition when i add new stops for the next route primary key will not allow that can u please suggest the primary key and foreign key schema

Comment: @MurlidharThakur, I've added some clarification. Note the primary key of `BusRouteBusStops` that lets you add as many atop as you wish.

Comment: I need to retrieve BusNo and BusRoute on the basis to two BusStop in two textbox.If both of them fond in the same bus no then show the busNo and BusRoute

Answer (score 0):

To resolve a `m:n` relation, you normally use an additional table. As you have everything in one table right now, that means two additional tables for you.

### Table structure

```
bus_stop: id, name

bus_route: id, description

stop_to_route_relation: bus_route, bus_stop
```

#### Example

```
bus_stop
--------------------
| id | name        |
--------------------
|  1 | CityA       |
--------------------
|  2 | CityB       |
--------------------
|  3 | CityC       |
--------------------

bus_route
-----------------------------
| id | bus_no | description |
-----------------------------
|  1 |  5     | CityA to B  |
-----------------------------
|  2 |  5     | CityA to C  |
-----------------------------

stop_to_route_relation
------------------------
| bus_route | bus_stop |
------------------------
|  1        |  1       |
------------------------
|  1        |  2       |
------------------------
|  2        |  1       |
------------------------
|  2        |  3       |
------------------------
```

### Example query

```
select 
    br.bus_no, 
    bs.name 
from 
    bus_route br 
left join stop_to_route_relation str on (br.id = str.bus_route) 
left join bus_stop bs on (str.bus_stop = bs.id);
```

Comment: Tell me how to retrieve the BusNo and BusRoute If two Busstops contains the same Busno and BusRoute.

Comment: I just added an extra col in bus route, for the bus number, is it more clear now?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to normalize BusStop field then you need to make a new table for it. Like this:

```
Table: Bus
===================================
| BusNo | BusRoute                
===================================
| 1     | Rajendra Nagar to Noida 
===================================

Table: BusStop
--------------------------
| BusNo | BusStop        
--------------------------
| 1     | Apsara         
--------------------------
| 1     | Shahadara      
--------------------------
| 1     | Shakarpur      
--------------------------
| 1     | Mother Dairy   
--------------------------
```

In the BusStop table the BusNo is the Foreign Key that links it to Bus table.

You mentioned that you have 1000 BusNo so I guess it will require a lot of resources since normalizing it will need more rows for saving the BusStop for each BusNo. For instance, each BusNo has 5 BusStops then your new table for BusStop will approximately have 1000 x 5 rows (Your saving every BusStop of Bus in the table). The advantage that I see here is you can do more queries in normalizing it. You weigh the pros and cons in deciding. Goodluck.

Comment: Bus stops happen in sequence.

Comment: Oh ok. It's not mentioned anyway.  I have no idea about that. I can add another field which will be called "Order". It can be added in BusStop table to handle that.

Comment: You have no idea about bus stops? Either a life of immense privilege or immense poverty. Either way, `order` is a reserved word in SQL - a poor choice for column/table identifier. ;-)

Comment: It's ok. I can always change the variable name ones my IDE highlights it as keyword. I don't remember exactly everything but the idea is there. Thanks for the reminder nonetheless. By the way, I'm a poor guy so I always walk whenever.

Comment: Well, it's the healthiest option